# How to fit DocuSign to my application

Tags: docusignapi

I have a web application that sends some details in an email to recipients and I need them to confirm the details and sign them. It's not a document I'm sending them just a few details inline.

What does DocuSign consider that? Document signing, embedded signing or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put together a text file (not really a PDF or a Word Doc) and just send that.  DocuSign supports that as well.

Check out the recipes to do that here: http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument